# How to make div work for 100% height and not only for iframe?

Tags: html, css, height, stylesheet

I have a layout with a 100% height for the content area. The problem is that it makes an iframe work perfectly for 100% height, but I cannot get it to work for a regular div. Is there a way to make the height 100% for the div? The white area should be filled with a black area but it does not. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/mp8nr/1/

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would work if you set the height of `.inner-content` to 100% too:

```
.inner-content {
    margin-bottom: -109px;
    padding-top: 109px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This give a scroll bar tho :\

Comment: That won't work well, as the class is also used for other elements in the page...

Comment: I didn't realize it was used more than once. @TruMan1, the idea is basically to set the height of the container to 100%. You might want to give the container an ID so that you can select it more easily.

Answer (score 1):

Set your inner-content class to

```
height: 100%;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using position:absolute

http://jsfiddle.net/adrianjmartin/mp8nr/27/

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the parent element height also:

```
<section role="main" id="content">
  <div class="inner-content" style="height: 100%">
```

(This should of course go in the style sheet somehow... You use the class for other elements in the page, that's why I didn't put it there...)